# How To Add Text to Side of Object/Mesh?

Tags: mesh, text-object

This seems like a simple thing to do, but I can't quite figure out how to do it. I want to add a label (text) onto the sides of my object like in this picture:

[image]

What is the best way to go about this? For reference, this is what my mesh looks like now:

[image]

NOTE: The text should fold over the top and bottom of the cover as shown above; AND I need a method that will work with importing it to Unreal Engine 5.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to UV unwrap the object and place the UVs on an image texture accordingly. Maybe you should watch tutorials on UV unwrapping - because if you need this more often, it is worth learning it more in-depth instead of just getting a quick answer only for this specific case.

Answer (score 4):

Select all the cylinder faces, switch to front view and unwrap with the *Cylinder Projection* option, then select the top and bottom face and simply unwrap:

[image]